# iOS, Core Data: set argument is not an NSSet error when counting an NSSet

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsset

Such error happens sometimes when listing the same tableView, I mean sometimes yes and sometimes no. When I try to check retrieved `NSSet` for if he contains any objects:

```
if(coin.dublicates.count > 0)
```

I get error :

> *** -[NSMutableSet unionSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'

What would be the reason for such error? 
whole method listing:

```
if(period.regions.count == 0) {

    for(Nominal *nominal in period.nominals) {

        if(nominal.coins.count>0) {

            counter+=[[nominal.coins filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"listed==%@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]]count];
            for(Coin *coin in nominal.coins)
            {

                if(coin.dublicates.count > 0) {

                    counter+=coin.dublicates.count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

screenshot:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nil relationship therefore nothing to count?

Comment: It may be nil and may be not.

Comment: Should I check for nil? if(coin.dublicates != nil)

Comment: Just a simple if (coin.duplicates) { // } works in ObjC to test for nil

Comment: Exactly this way I have changed my code right now. It also works and no crushes for a moment. Make an official answer I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the NSSet is not nil before evaluating its count.

```
if (coin.dublicates) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't a nil set return 0 for the count? Is this a fetched property?

Comment: Fetched property and it worked ok in iOS7, but after I switched to the latest xCode the crushes began to appear sometimes. So, checking for nil looks like solution.